# Django - select options

Tags: html, python, django

Estou tentando colocar os nomes dos coordenadores nos options de um select buscando pelo  banco de dados, já dei uma pesquisada e parece que há uma outra forma de utilizar o select no django, mas não ficou muito claro, por isso estou postando aqui meu codigo para ver se alguem consegue me esclarecer as duvidas.

Este é a parte da views:

```
contexto ={
    'coordenadores': Coordenador.objects.all()
}
...
return render(request, 'formDisciplina.html', contexto)
```

Aqui abaixo é o template:

```
<p><label name='idcoordenador'>Coordenador: </label>
    <select name='idcoordenador'>
        <option>-----Selecione-----</option>
        {% for a in coordenadores %}
            <option values= {{ a.id }}> {{ a.name }} </option>
        {% endfor %}

    </select>
</p>
```

Comment: Veja essa outra [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788388/how-do-i-use-djangos-form-framework-for-select-options), acredito que a mesma satisfaça a sua.

Comment: Ja pesquisei mas nao ficou muito claro, eu crio a classe nna views mesmo ? E nos options posso inserir os dados de um bd com um for ?

Comment: Do jeito que você fez está ok também. A forma que o Isael apontou é utilizando o Django Forms que cuida da renderização dos elementos do formulário para você mas isso requer um tempinho para entender como os Forms funcionam.

Answer (score 5):

```
#arquivo forms.py
from django import forms

class MeuForm(forms.Form):
    #no choices eu fiz um list comprehension que apenas gera um list [a,b,c...z] que vai ser renderizado no select
    coordenadores = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[('0', '--Selecione--')]+    [(coordenador.id, coordenador.name) for coordenador in Coordenador.objects.all()])
```

na sua view você cria uma instância do form e passa para o template formDisciplina.html

```
#views.py
from forms import MeuForm
from models import Coordenador
contexto ={
'meu_form': MeuForm()
}
...
return render(request, 'formDisciplina.html', contexto)
```

No template basta chamar meu_form

```
<form action="/minha_acao/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ meu_form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: entendi, cria na views uma classe herdando o forms.Form  e depois uso o metodo ChoiceField.. agora ficou bem mais claro muito obrigado

Comment: boa, funcionou para mim. Agora preciso aprender como colocar outras coisas no form. Por exemplo: placeholder.

Answer (score 3):

sem que ja passou muito tempo.. porém segue um jeito mais simples

View:

```
task = Task.objects.all()

    data = {
        'task': task
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', data)
```

Html:

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm">
    <option>Selecione</option>
    {% if task %}
        {% for item in task %}
            <option>{{ item.TaskName }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
     {% else %}
     {% endif %}
 </select>
```